# AWS CloudFormation Error: !Join object requires two parameters, (1) a string delimiter and (2) a list of strings to be joined

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I'm getting an error in CloudFormation using the !Join function:

**Template error: every Fn::Join object requires two parameters, (1) a string delimiter and (2) a list of strings to be joined or a function that returns a list of strings (such as Fn::GetAZs) to be joined.**

My Code:

```
  RDSSubnetGroup:
    Type: AWS::RDS::DBSubnetGroup
    Condition: CreationRDS
    Properties:
       DBSubnetGroupDescription: !Ref RDSName
       SubnetIds: !Ref SubnetIds
  
  RDSAuroraServerless:
    Type: AWS::RDS::DBCluster
    Condition: CreationRDS
    Properties:
      Engine: aurora-mysql
      EngineMode: serverless
      EngineVersion: !Ref EngineVersion
      DatabaseName: !Ref RDSName
      MasterUsername: admin
      MasterUserPassword: !Ref MasterUserPassword
      DBClusterIdentifier: !Ref RDSName
      ScalingConfiguration:
        MinCapacity: 1
        MaxCapacity: 2
        SecondsUntilAutoPause: 300
      BackupRetentionPeriod: 7
      DeletionProtection: false
      VpcSecurityGroupIds:
        - !Ref SecurityGroup
      DBSubnetGroupName: !Ref RDSSubnetGroup

Outputs:
  JDBCOutput:
    Condition: CreationRDS
    Value: 
      !Join [ '', [!GetAtt RDSAuroraServerless.Endpoint.Address, /, !Ref RDSName] ]
```

Can you help me and show me where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Did you try `!Join [ "", [!GetAtt RDSAuroraServerless.Endpoint.Address, "/", !Ref RDSName] ]` with quotes around the / character

Comment: @Shawn Didn't work, returned the same error :(

Comment: The `Join` is correct. Are you sure that the error originates in the `Outputs`? Maybe you have different joins in your code, or the code posted in SO is not the real code you are using.

Comment: @Marcin the real code is this same.
It does, because this error only appears when I add the Outputs in the CF

Comment: Then, there is nothing apparent which your `Join`. It should work. So the  root cause may be outside of that code.

Comment: I found the error, I had referenced the !Join wrongly elsewhere

Comment: So basically as I wrote: " Maybe you have different joins in your code"?:-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments.

The `Join` statement in the question is **correct**. Upon further investigation, the OP found the problem in **other** `Join` (not shown in the question), which lead to solution.